# Amortization Schedule

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a new to python as a whole coming from COBOL.
I am trying to create a program to take user input about a loan, and then output a schedule of payments and how they will affect the balance of the loan.

```
#ACCEPTS USER INPUT AND ASSIGNS VALUES
print('lets try to amortize a loan')
input()
print('when will this loan begin?')
year = int(input('year: '))
month = int(input('month: '))
day = int(input('day: '))
principal = float(input('give me a loan amount: '))
rate = float(input('give me an interest rate in decimal form: '))
term = int(input('how many year will this loan be for: '))
comp = int(input('how many times a year will payments be made: '))
monthly = float(input('what will the payment amount be: '))

#DISPLAYS HOW THE SYSTEM TOOK USER INPUT
print('lets take a look at these values')
input()
print('\n', '$', principal,
      '\n', (rate*100), '%',
      '\n', term, 'years',
      '\n', 'paying ', comp, 'times per year',
      '\n', 'beginning:', month, '/', day, '/', year,
      '\n', 'our monthly payment is $', monthly)
input()

#CALCULATES PERDIEM
perdiem = ((principal * rate) / 365)
print('our perdiem will be $', round(perdiem, 4))
print('with this we can calculate a months payment')
input()
print('first lets try and structure for the first month')

#BELOW IS TESTING TO SEE HOW MANY DAYS ARE IN A BILLING CYCLE
if month == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 8 or 10 or 12:
    NumDays = 31
elif month == 4 or 6 or 9 or 11:
    NumDays = 30
elif month == 2 and (year % 4) != 0:
    NumDays = 28
elif month == 2 and (year % 4) == 0:
    NumDays = 29

print('so our first month would have', NumDays, 'days of perdiem')
input()
print('FIRST MONTH PAYMENT')

#BELOW TESTS TO SEE WHAT MONTH NEEDS TO BE DISPLAYED
if month == 12:
    NextMonth = month - 11
    NextYear = year + 1
else:
    NextMonth = month + 1
    NextYear = year

#DISPLAYS FIRST MONTHS DATA
print('Date:', NextMonth, '/', day, '/', NextYear)
PayNum = 1
print('Payment: #', PayNum)
print('Payment Amount: $', monthly)
print('Days this cycle:', NumDays)
MonthInt = round((perdiem * NumDays), 2)
print('Months Interest: $', MonthInt)
MonthP = round((monthly - MonthInt), 2)
print('Months Principal: $', MonthP)
balance = round((principal - MonthP), 2)
print('Remainder: $', balance)
input()
```

basically I would want the same information from the first months pay to be repeated with values being adjusted (paynum +1, nextmonth +1, balance - monthp, etc) until the balance is less than the monthly payment.

I have tried variations of if and while statements but cant seem to structure anything that works. My values will only adjust the one time and cant seem to continually overwrite values.
Help is appreciated on this issue as well as suggestions to better write my existing code.

Comment: You'll get much better help if you post a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): show your best attempt at one of those loops, along with actual and desired output.  Get rid of all the input overhead that's not part of the problem; just directly assign the principal, period, etc.

Comment: [Here](http://pbpython.com/amortization-model-revised.html) is a solid start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal take is that `input()` function should be avoided at all costs when learning python: (a) it diverts you from structuring code in a modular way, (b) it is rarely used to applications - the interfaces are usually command line arguments or direct function calls.

The code you supply is a bit hard to follow, even though I appreciate it is linked to COBOL style and culture. The best thing to do is to devise your problem into smaller subtasks and test how they work in separation. This way you will know where your problem is, and it would be easier to focus your question (and attention of people answering).

My understanding is that the core idea of your script is calculating monthly payments and loan amortisation. Consider following code:

```
# FIXME: missing compound interest
def perdiem(amount, rate):
    return (amount * rate) / 365


def days_per_month(month, year):
    if month in [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]:
        return 31
    elif month in [4, 6, 9, 11]:
        return 30
    elif month == 2:
        if (year % 4) == 0:
            return 29
        else:
            return 28
    else:
        raise ValueError('month expected', month)


def next_month(month, year):
    if month == 12:
        next_month = 1
        next_year = year + 1
    else:
        next_month = month + 1
        next_year = year
    return next_month, next_year

def monthly_interest(principal, days, rate):
    return perdiem(principal, rate) * days


def monthly_principal(monthly_payment, current_interest_payment):
    return monthly_payment - current_interest_payment

def yield_expected_payment_schedule(start_year, 
                                    start_month, 
                                    initial_amount, 
                                    rate,
                                    duration_in_years,
                                    monthly_payment):
    year = start_year
    month = start_month
    amount = initial_amount 
    for t in range(duration_in_years * 12 + 1):
        days = days_per_month(month, year)
        interest_due = monthly_interest(amount, days, rate)
        if amount > 0:
            yield {'balance at month start': amount,
                   'interest due': monthly_interest(amount, days, rate),  
                   'year': year,
                   'month': month
                   } 
        amount = amount - (monthly_payment - interest_due)
        month, year = next_month(month, year)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arg_dict1 = dict(start_year=1965, 
                     start_month=8, 
                     initial_amount=1000, 
                     rate=0.05,
                     duration_in_years=1,
                     monthly_payment=85.61)        
    schedule = list(yield_expected_payment_schedule(**arg_dict1))
    print(schedule)
```

Some follow-up thoughts:

- try separate your argument collection, calculation and result presentation as much as possible
- when you specifiy amount and duration you just know the monthly payment as an annuity, makes no sense to allow enter them both, consider devising `evaluate_monthly_payment()`
- separate expected payments, amount paid and current amount due to make it more realistic
- resort to `datatime.date` type and corresponding functions for date manipulation.

Hope it's useful.

Comment: Wow - this is a nice answer. I don't know that most people would take the time to help someone out on what is basically a programming language translation problem. +1

Comment: @HFBrowning - Indeed a language translation, but I see it as my small tribute to COBOL legacy. Life if much simplier these days with contempory high-level programming languages.

Comment: Hello, how come you don't use the function monthly_principal?

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
Hare is the Code for Amortization Schedule Calculator in Python
"""

def MortgageAmortizationSchedule(loan, months, interest):
    monthlyPay = loan * (interest * (1 + interest) ** months / ((1 + interest) ** months - 1))
    #print(-round(numpy.pmt(interest, months, loan), 2))
    payment = monthlyPay
    month = 1
    monthlyInterest = interest * loan
    principal = payment - monthlyInterest
    balance = loan - principal
    total_interest_paid = 0
    
    print("#" * 105)
    print("{0:>15}{1:>20} {2:>20} {3:>20} {4:>20}".format("Payment Month", "Principal Paid", "Interest Paid",
                                                              "Monthly Payment", "Mortgage Balance"))
    print("#" * 105)

    print("{0:>15}{1:>20,.2f} {2:>20,.2f} {3:>20,.2f} {4:>20,.2f}".format(month, principal, monthlyInterest,
                                                                                 payment, balance))
    while balance > 0:
        monthlyInterest = interest * balance
        principal = payment - monthlyInterest
        balance = balance - principal
        month += 1
        total_interest_paid += monthlyInterest

        if balance <= 0:
            balance = 0
       
        print("{0:>15}{1:>20,.2f} {2:>20,.2f} {3:>20,.2f} {4:>20,.2f}".format(month, principal, monthlyInterest,
                                                                                 payment, balance))

    print("#" * 105)
    print("Total interest paid will be:  ${0:,.2f}".format((payment * month) - loan))
    print("Total principal paid will be:  ${0:,.2f}".format(loan))
    print("#" * 105)


############################## Inputs ##############################
loan = float(input('Enter Loan/Mortgage Amount: '))
years = float(input('Enter Loan Term/Period in years: '))
interest = float(input('Enter annual interest rate for this loan: '))
interest = interest / 12 / 100
months = years * 12

############## Create Amortization Schedule Calculator #############
MortgageAmortizationSchedule(loan, months, interest)
```